# Regex.Replace: How to use $groups followed by numbers

Tags: .net, regex

With Regex::Replace we can use $1, $2, ... to match corresponding groups. But how can I use $1 followed by number. E.g. to replace 6 with 678?

```
 Regex::Replace(text, "(6)", '$178');
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to use the alternate syntax:

```
Regex::Replace(text, "(6)", "${1}78");
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems I can use $`

```
Regex::Replace(text, "(6)", '$1$`78');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use backreferences to capture a named group and replace that named group with whatever you want. 
[view this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)

Comment: It would be nice to add an example. The documentation you point at is quite bulky.