# VSCode regex find & replace submatch math?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

```
%s@{fileID: \(213[0-9]*\)@\='{fileID: '.(submatch(1)-1900)@
```

I am using this regex search and replace command in vim to subtract a constant from each matching id.

I can do the regex find in VSCode but how can I reference the `submatch` for maths & replace? `submatch(1)` does not work in VSCode?

Thanks.

Comment: This is now a backlog candidate: [Regex Find/Replace with named capture groups](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195724)

Answer (score 774, accepted):

Given a regular expression of `(foobar)` you can reference the first group using `$1` and so on if you have more groups in the replace input field.

Comment: asked again diffrently here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283300/vscode-sub-match-evaluate-instead-of-concatenate

Comment: I had to replace `<p>(.*)</p>` with `<p>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$1\n\t\t\t\t\t</p>` for a 2000 line file. Imagine me doing it manually.

Comment: ... and $0 to reference the full matched string (no parentheses needed). This is useful if you want to add to the search string, as in replacing `"Bond"` by `"$0, James $0"`.

Comment: Dont forget to click the .* button to tell vsc you entering regex

Comment: ~~What if my replacement string has a number right after the reference? E.g. replace _(6)_ with _678_? `$178` would obviously not work. In some implementations there is [a special syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/811140/2822719)  (`${1}78`) for that, but at least that one doesn't work in VS Code. Do you happen to know what will?~~ | **Nevermind, `$178` just magically works! ‍♂️**

Comment: @MarcusMangelsdorf The magic was a heuristics: there were fewer than 178 captures, and fewer than 17. ${1} is more robust.

Comment: This is now a backlog candidate: [Regex Find/Replace with named capture groups](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195724)

Answer (score 211):

To augment Benjamin's answer with an example:

```
Find        Carrots(With)Dip(Are)Yummy
Replace     Bananas$1Mustard$2Gross
Result      BananasWithMustardAreGross
```

Anything in the parentheses can be a regular expression.

Comment: This one reminded me I should escape the parenthesis if I'm doing a regex on if statement.

Answer (score 123):

Just to add another example:

I was replacing src attr in img html tags, but i needed to replace only the src and keep any text between the img declaration and src attribute.

I used the find+replace tool (ctrl+h) as in the image:
[image: Find and replace]

Comment: for me this works inconsistently - though selection forks correct, the output sometimes keeps `$1` without replacement

Comment: Hi, @godblessstrawberry, can you share your search and replacement strings?

Comment: hi @Diogo I was trying to replace projectwide `\[innerHtml\]\s*=\s*"'(.*)'\s*\|\s*translate\s*"` with `myTranslate="$1"` and it was skipping keys randomly and inserting $1 instead of group value sometimes. update to 1.28.0 resolved this issue

Comment: I ran into the same problem as @godblessstrawberry, doing a global replace across all my files with the regex ' (and|or\+|\-)\n( *)' and the replacement string '\n$2$1 ' sometimes correctly shifted the binary operator to the start of the newline but in other cases just inserted $2$1. Would appear to be a bug in VSCodium

Comment: @godblessstrawberry, check this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/81825. If it do not apply for you, provide more info and open an issue there.

Comment: This regex is a bit dangerous as it won't work when there are multiple `img` tags in one line or the three letters `img` appear somewhere in the text. Something like `(<img[^>]*)(src=)` might be a better solution.

Answer (score 64):

For beginners, the accepted answer is correct, but a little terse if you're not that familiar with either VSC or Regex.

So, in case this is your first contact with either:

To find and *modify* text,

1. In the "Find" step, you can use regex with "capturing groups," e.g. `I want to find (group1) and (group2)`, using parentheses.  This would find the same text as `I want to find group1 and group2`, but with the difference that you can then reference `group1` and `group2` in the next step:
2. In the "Replace" step, you can refer to the capturing groups via `$1`, `$2` etc, so you could change the sentence to `I found $1 and $2  having a picnic`, which would output `I found group1 and group2 having a picnic.`

Notes:

- Instead of just a string, anything inside or outside the `()` can be a regular expression.
- `$0` refers to the whole match

Comment: Honestly, the best answer for beginners such as myself to `regex`.

Answer (score 28):

In my case $1 was not working, but $0 works fine for my purpose.

In this case I was trying to replace strings with the correct format to translate them in Laravel, I hope this could be useful to someone else because it took me a while to sort it out!

```
Search: (?<=<div>).*?(?=</div>)
Replace: {{ __('$0') }}
```

[Regex Replace String for Laravel Translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omNRu.png)

Comment: Is that possible for you copy your edit your post and copy the code instead of the image? It would be better for visualization.

Answer (score 11):

Just another example for someone figuring out.

In this example, I've added `####` to the start of the string and placed the first group `$1` after that. Everything outside group `(.*)` is going to be deleted.

```bash
<h4.*">(.*)</h4>
#### $1
```

[image]

```bash
# before: 
<h4 id="extract-inline-json-with-regex">Extract inline JSON data with Regex</h4>

# after:
#### Extract inline JSON data with Regex
```

Answer (score 9):

Another simple example:

```
Search: style="(.+?)"
Replace: css={css`$1`}
```

Useful for converting HTML to JSX with emotion/css!

Answer (score 0):

In "files to include"

```
./REPONAME/**/{application_stress*,application_k8s*}
./REPONAME/**/application_*{stress*,k8s*}
./REPONAME/**/{*_stress*,*_k8s*}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Find: (loadImage([^"]*))(.[^"]*)

Replaces <img **[loadImage]="act.landing.image"**

and then you can replace if you needed to replace "act.landing.image"
Replace: src]=$3

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug in my vscode and $1 would not fill in the capturing group but literally `$1`. (I was searching and replacing globally). It seemed that global search was finding results with a "wrong/weird" regex.

I solved it using the following steps:

1. Test if your regex is working in a specific file first. (using windows `ctrl + h`)
2. If your regex is working inside a single file it should work as expected using global search and replace with $1 etc.

In my specific case

- `(formcontrol(?:name)?[^>\n]*)\[disabled\]` was giving results in global search but not in a single file.
- I changed it to `(formcontrol(?:name)?(?:[^>]|[\r\n])*)\[disabled\]` for it to work in a single file. It then also worked globally.

I hope this helps someone.