# vscode regex sub match evaluate instead of concatenate?

Tags: regex, math, visual-studio-code

```
Test 300
Test 301
Test 302
```

I can use regex find to loop through these:

```
Test (3[0-9]*)
```

When I try replace with math it concatenates instead of evaluates?

```
Test $1-100
```

So, it becomes:

```
Test 300-100
```

Is it possible to evaluate instead of concatenate, so it becomes:

```
Test 200
```

Thanks.

Comment: The match `$1` is a **string**, to perform mathematical operations you need to cast them to Number.

Comment: It is not possible in any regex flavor.

Comment: it works in vim regex: %s@{fileID: \(213[0-9]*\)@\='{fileID: '.(submatch(1)-1900)@

Comment: %s@Test (3[0-9]*)@\='Test '.(submatch(1)-100)@

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2902

Comment: sarcastic thanks. it is not a dupe... i asked both. the other one was answered this one has an open issue on github.

Comment: @RakkaRage In Vim, the example you supplied does not contain a *string* replacement pattern, it is a *callable* variation. In many languages, it is possible to do the same (`Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=fileID:\s*)213\d*", x => $"{int.Parse(x.Value)-1900}")`, but it is not possible with *string* replacement patterns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the VS Code [Super Replace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jebbs.super-replace) extension to achieve this.

**Find** field is the regular expression

**Replace** is the replace expression. Sub match with `$$index` syntax will be resolved using the function in **Processing function** field

Here is an example of use that answers your question :

[image: Super Replace VS Code demo]

Answer (score 1):

There are more extensions that can do this now, including one I wrote [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview).

With this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",                     // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(?<=Test\\s)(3\\d\\d)",  // get 300+ in capture group 1
    "replace": "$${ return $1 - 100 }",      // subtract 100 from capture group 1
    "isRegex": true
  }
}
```

[image: evaluate math on a capture group]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [Regex Text Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.regex-text-gen)

- select the numbers with multi cursors
- execute command: **Generate text based on Regular Expression (regex)**
- for original regex use: `(.*)`
- for generator regex use: `{{=N[1]-100}}`