# VSCode: Replace text doing math

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-code

I want to replace numbers with some math calc based on the numbers.

For example, I have the following text

```
...
foo 1 42 3
bar 4 5 67
...
```

Using `Ctrl+f` tool with the regex `(.+) ([\d]+) ([\d]+) ([\d]+)`, I already can use the values with `$1`, `$2`, `$3`... But I need some way to, for example, sum the values.

If I use a replace regex like `Total $1: $2 + $3 + $4`, I get:

```
...
Total foo: 1 + 42 + 3
Total bar: 4 + 5 + 67
...
```

but actually I want

```
...
Total foo: 46
Total bar: 76
...
```

Actually, I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vscode regex sub match evaluate instead of concatenate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283300/vscode-regex-sub-match-evaluate-instead-of-concatenate)

Answer (score 4):

Math in regex replace in vscode is not possible (yet?)

There is an open issue in vscode's github:  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2902

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an extension that can do this pretty easily: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview).

So for the OP's question, you could use this keybinding (in `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",                     // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "find": "(.+) (\\d+) (\\d+) (\\d+)",
    "replace": "$${ return `Total $1: ` + ($2 + $3 + $4) }",
    "isRegex": true,

    // "restrictFind": "document"  // or line, selections, once
  }
},
```

Or you can set that up as a command in your `settings.json`.  See the Readme.

```
$${ `Total $1: ` + ($2 + $3 + $4) }
```

will perform a javascript operation.  In this case using `$1` as part of a string (delimited by backticks) and adding `$2, $3 and $4` as Numbers.  Demo:

[image: doing math on a find and replace]