# I don't want to manually replace id: 1, id: 1, id: 1, into id: 1, id: 2, id: 3 in a object in vs code anymore

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I believe that this isn't duplicate. The suggested answer recomennds to use an extention, but I want to use the official feature from vscode.

I have this code:

```
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Ken'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Ryu'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Vega'
  },
```

I want to make it into this:

```
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Ken'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ryu'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Vega'
  },
```

I did some research on it, and turns out I can use a feature 'find' and 'replace' in vs code. You can access it from the menu bar 'Edit'.

[image: This is the function]

In the find box, I put 'id: \d+', and in the replace, I put 'id: $[${++counter}]'.
However, vs code doesn't recognize the expression. It just prints out 'id: $[${++counter}]', not like 'id: 1, id: 2...' and so on.

I don't even know if the way I did was correct or not...

Is there anyone who knows how to do it correctly?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283300/vscode-regex-sub-match-evaluate-instead-of-concatenate

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to use the feature from vscode that comes wth by default...

Comment: Where is the VS Code documentation where you read about this syntax for regex find-and-replace? I've never seen it before.

Comment: Ah, I see...that syntax came from chatGPT...Do you happen to know the correct syntax to do that?

Comment: Why don't you ask ChatGPT to find the documentation, and you can both learn together that this syntax is completely made up.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that it actually didn't exsit... Now I'm going to try to use Super Replace for that

Comment: or you can use **Regex Text Generator**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75911867/9938317

Comment: ChatGPT is a dumb parrot, don't ask it anything related to programming or physics

Comment: almost everything in VSC is done with extension (build in or installed) so try to do something when you disable all, yes all, extension also the build-in s

Comment: Haha I thought chatGPT was good for things like especially programming, because  there are always correct answers decided like Math, compered to something like art.

Comment: Also, thanks for lettking me know about Regex Text Generator, I'm going to try that with it

Comment: Programming _IS_ art.

Comment: ChatGPT is really bad at math, even at basic math. ChatGPT guesses texts. It's not an AI that understands the context of your question.

Answer (score 0):

**you can do it easily in your code:**

const array = [{
id: 1,
name: 'Ken'
},
{
id: 1,
name: 'Ryu'
},
{
id: 1,
name: 'Vega'
}]

array.forEach((item, ind) => { item.id = ind})

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I just want to edit them with the feature from vs code.