# Is there a way to select all text string content in a whole document at once in Visual Studio?

Tags: html, macos, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for a quick way to, for example, if this was my HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>This is a text line</p>
</html>
```

Select only ***Title***, ***Hello*** and ***This is a text line*** all at once, ignoring the tags and non-string code.

Is there a keyboard shortcut or a plugin to do it? I'm working with MacOS on a Mac keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any shortcut or plugin to do this but you could use a regular expression to replace all of the html tags with nothing:

Find `'<[^>]*>'` 
Replace: `''`

eg: https://regex101.com/r/zYb01t/1

Alternatively, if none of the content is hidden you could view the rendered html in a browser, select all <kbd>⌘A</kbd> and copy all the text <kbd>⌘C</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex:

`(<\w+>)(.*)(<\/\w+>)` as show for your code [here](https://regex101.com/r/YyaVg9/1). The parentheses group the output. What you want is group number two ( `(.*)` ). According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34719092/10810447) you can achieve this is VScode by using `$2`.